# How to plot many datasets from numpy list with matplotlib

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib

I'm new to Python and struggling with plotting many curves on one graph with matplotlib.

I have 50 data files.  I've read them all in and stored them in a 3D numpy list.  First dimension is the filenumber, 2nd dimension is the time, 3rd dimension is the parameter being measured (time, pressure, ...).  For a single file the data might look like this:

(time) (pressure)
1       3.4
2       5.1
3       5.1
4       5.1
5       7.8

I want to plot all fifty time vs. pressure curves on one graph.  What I have so far is:

```
plt.plot(\
    clipData[0,:,0], clipData[0,:,1],\
    clipData[1,:,0], clipData[1,:,1],\
    clipData[2,:,0], clipData[2,:,1])
plt.show()
```

This works fine for the first three curves, but I figure there must be a way to do this with out manually generating the list out to 50.  I thought about using a loop to build the list as a long string and then shoving this string into plot().

```
guts = 'clipData[0,:,0], clipData[0,:,1]'
plt.plot(guts)
plt.show
```

But my simple test made it clear I was doing something very wrong.

Any help would be appreciated, I'm sure there's an elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like :

```
for i in range(50):
    plt.plot(clipData[i,:,0], clipData[i,:,1])
plt.show()
```

Because when you use 
    `guts = 'clipData[0,:,0], clipData[0,:,1]'` 
`guts` is just a string which cannot be plotted.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass two 2D arrays to `plot`. Each column in the first array will be plotted against the corresponding column of the second array.

```
plt.plot(clipData[:, :, 0].T, clipData[:, :, 1].T)
```

Plotting in this way you are somewhat limited when specifying line properties, in particular you can't pass a label for each line. For full control over line properties plotting in a loop can be more convenient.

Comment: Nice. Much cleaner than my solution.

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(0,len(clipData)):
    plt.plot(clipData[i,:,0],clipData[i,:,1])
plt.show()
```

This way your plotting routine will run for any length of clipData or if you change it in the future.

Comment: That worked great, thank you.  How does len() know that you wanted the dimension of the first axis of the list.  Does it default to the first axis?  I've been saying things like len(clipData[:,0,0]), but that's apparently not needed.

Comment: I am not super familiar with the inner workings of numpy arrays. But there is a lot of information avaialble here: 
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#arrays-indexing

and https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html

and https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len.

From the last.

"len: Return the length (the number of items) of an object." 

Sorry I can't help more, that is a nuance that I cannot remember off the top of my head.

Comment: @tfinan74 Goyo's answer is better than mine, much more concise!

Comment: @tfinan74 `len` will return the first dimension. You can use `clipData.shape[0]` as well.